Manually number theorems natively in Lyx
How do I manually number theorems natively in Lyx?
In Latex, another answer tells me I can manually number theorems like this (choosing the number 8):
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{innercustomthm}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{customthm}[1]%
    {\renewcommand\theinnercustomthm{#1}\innercustomthm}
    {\endinnercustomthm}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{customthm}{8}\label{eight}
Every theorem must be numbered by hand.
\end{customthm}

Here is a cross-reference to theorem~\ref{eight}. 
\end{document}

which outputs:

But I would like to do this natively in Lyx, so it looks like this:

Furthermore, I want to be able to manually choose the number of the theorem. Ideally I could also allow for letters like Theorem B2.

Welcome to TeX.SE.

I've taken the liberty of turning your (LaTeX) code snippet into a full-fledged minimum working example. Feel free to revert.

I'd have to be in your shoes to say with certainty that manual numbering is a bad idea, but I'll say it anyway.  :)
That said, one approach could be use the Theorem* environment  using the module Theorem (unnumbered) and probably the other theorems modules too, but I only test this module.
Then, make Theorem* and the with the contextual menu you can add a  Additional Theorem Text Alt+A 1 to put a pseudo counter. Therefore it can be be "8", "B8" or "eight" or whatever, and then use Textual reference to link it.  You can also reference (but not link) the label directly, but note that other cross-reference will not work because there are not a any real counter here.
Example (warning: colors will be another in your LyX):



The first page of the PDF should show this:



And the Code Preview Pane should show this:
should show this:
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.7 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem*{thm*}{\protect\theoremname}

\makeatother

\providecommand{\theoremname}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\section*{Test}

Normal next with reference to theorem \nameref{eight} \vpageref{eight}.
The next is the theorem \nameref{four}. One more link to the last
theorem \nameref{foo} \vpageref{foo}. This one have the label \emph{foo}.
\begin{thm*}[8]

This is the theorem with label eight \label{eight}
\end{thm*}
More normal text 
\begin{thm*}[B4]

This is the theorem four \label{four}
\end{thm*}
\newpage{}
\begin{thm*}[whatever]
 \label{foo} This is the theorem of whatever
\end{thm*}

\end{document}

  


Thanks! I may make another post RE a non-manual approach for my use-case. For now, how do I use Textual reference? I don't love the parentheses in Additional Theorem Text, but I'll live with it.

@AlexBoche  How use Textaul Reference? Insert →  Cross-reference → Available labels →(select the label)  → Reference Format → (select "Textual reference", the 6th option) → OK (or Apply).
